# Keycloak role-ldap-mapper sync

Tags: jboss, synchronization, wildfly, roles, keycloak

I am struggling with the keycloak role-ldap-mapper. We have an Active Directory Service internally where Users can ask for roles. Roles are assigned/removed by another tool and saved into the memberOf Attribute in AD.
Keycloak imports the roles correctly at the users first login, but somehow when the user is already there, roles are updated in AD, they are not synchronized to Keycloak. I just want roles to be synchronized regularly from AD to Keycloak, not the other way around (I am not supposed to write into the AD).
Is it a Bug? Works as Designed, or am I configuring something in the wrong way?

I am running 2 instances, Version 3.1.0 and 3.4.1.

I already played around with the LDAP - periodic synchronize changed/full feature but no success.
Do I have to specify the memberOf Attribute somehow specifically to be synchronized?

Thx for help.

[image: Role Mapper]

---

### Solution found:

I have updated Keycloak to the newest Version (3.4.3). Now it works for me. Seems to be an issue in the previous versions.